# How can I fix this error while loading a JSON File in Python

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to load JSON in python but I keep getting errors

```
import json

f = open('StudentJson.json', 'r')
data = json.load(f)

print(data.items())
```

The error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Chinyere\Documents\Python\Openpyxl\students.py", line 4, in <module>
    data = json.load(f)
  File "C:\Users\Chinyere\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\__init__.py", line 
   293, in load
  return loads(fp.read(),
  File "C:\Users\Chinyere\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
 return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\Chinyere\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\Chinyere\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
  raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

How can I go about this error.

Comment: Try `f = open('StudentJson.json', 'r', errors='ignore')`

Comment: Are you sure the file you're trying to load is actually valid JSON?

Comment: @larsks exactly; its hard to tell what the issue is when the json is not provided because that is clearly the issue lol

Comment: A UTF8-encoded file with BOM signature could cause this. Use `encoding='utf-8-sig'` when opening the file

Answer (score 0):

Try entering in your json file into a json linting service like this. It should highlight what is wrong with the json file

https://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0):

My experience is that this occurs when printing JSON data displayed via the powershell console. In fact, if you use the FLASK console itself etc. it will print the data there.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).